# Php redirect script using noise filter and google adsense?

Tags: php, google-analytics

So I want to create a redirect script that does 3 things in the following order:

1. Filters out the "noise" of where a person is coming from.  Basically, it should only track users coming from a specific location.  If users are coming from a different location, the script will stop executing the rest of the code.
2. Render Google Analytics code.  Once the code filters out the traffic and sees that the traffic is coming from the specified location, then the code will render Google Analytics to see how much traffic that specific site is sending.
3. Use a redirect code to send filtered traffic to desired site.

The goal of the script is to do an A/B test on some sites for a marketing campaign.  Need to see how much traffic a certain website is sending to the website I'm driving traffic to in comparison to other websites.  The script will only count traffic coming from the specified website using the noise filter (which I am guessing is a SERVER_HTTP variable or something like that), then it will render google analytics to monitor how much traffic is coming from the specified website, then lastly it will redirect traffic to the desired website.  The main challenge I am having is coming up with the code for step 1. steps 2 and 3 are easy but trying to figure out if I did step 1 right.

Answer (score 0):

No need to code that all by yourself. I had the same problem a few months back. Google has really great tools for A/B tests. Go here --> [www.google.com/websiteoptimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) It works great and has helped me a lot in optimizing my webpage, just like you aim to do!